# How to make a super capacitor jump starter that doesn't empty into battery?

Tags: supercapacitor

I have been watching videos on super capacitor jump starters for cars.

I figured out about 90% of how they work, but there is one last thing I don't understand.

The jump starters use a boost converter to charge up the capacitors from my lower voltage source, possibly even the partially depleted car battery. However in the videos, when they jump start the car, they do not disconnect the battery. Since the super capacitors are in parallel with the battery, shouldn't they push all of their current trying to balance the battery with their voltage?

I have been building my own version, and in order to jump start the vehicle I disconnect the battery from the car at the positive terminal and hook it up to the super capacitor bank. Is there a circuit that I can add that will prevent it from draining into the battery but will still allowed to discharge into the car's electrical system?

To see what I am talking about go to 12:00 in this video...
https://youtu.be/l_xojkGW2hY

My guess is maybe they have a high current MOSFET that can push up to 500A and some sort of circuit that senses when the voltage across the terminals drops suddenly from connection to the starter and triggers the MOSFET. How would you detect this if the battery was completely discharged?

Comment: You dont need to disconnect the battery. The capacitor has a circuit that detects you're trying to crank the vehicle, which activates discharge instead of charging off the battery.

Comment: @NatsuKage I assumed they had a circuit of some sort, hence the question.  What is in the circuit is my question.

Comment: As I recall, disconnecting the battery cable while the engine is running is usually a very bad idea.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it is disconnected before the engine is running.  The point is to disconnected it so the capacitor Bank is not drained into the depleted battery.  This would be like a dead short across the cap bank and might damage the battery if it is very depleted.  After the car starts the battery is reconnected.  I'm trying to figure out how to do it without disconnecting the battery.

Comment: Having the battery disconnected while the engine is running (even for a few seconds) is a Very Bad Idea.  Without the battery as  a load, the alternator output voltage will be uncontrolled, and will rise to a voltage dangerous to most electronics (and dnagerous to the alternator itself)..

Comment: @PeterBennett Most standard vehicle electrical systems come with voltage regulators anyway to ensure the alternator always produces a steady 13.5-14.5V no matter what happens to the RPM or to the LOAD.

Comment: @ManRow: - no - the battery is required to hold the alternator output voltage down to the 13.6 - 14.4 volt range.  I, and many others, have determined this experimentally (accidently) by disconnecting the battery and destroying electronics.  This is probably more common with boats, where we have a battery disconnect switch, than with cars.  An alternator "voltage" regulator effectively controls the alternator output current, not the voltage.

Comment: @PeterBennett That is not true -- read https://www.carparts.com/blog/a-short-course-on-charging-systems/ for reference. It *clearly* states, "*The voltage regulator monitors the voltage coming out of the alternator and, when it reaches a threshold of about 14.5 volts, the regulator reduces the current in the rotor to weaken the magnetic field. When the voltage drops below this threshold, the current to the rotor is increased.*" So, it *is* a full-fledged voltage regulator, and nothing short of that. If you are finding issues in older cars or other electrical systems, that is a separate issue.

Comment: Note -- either with respect to older cars or electrical systems, or even manufacturers "cutting corners" by using cheap components or buggy designs -- the reason you sometimes hear to "never disconnect" the battery when the car is running is simply just as a "general rule of thumb" to prevent *potentially* damaging "transients" to *potentially* vulnerable or poorly protected delicate electronic components if your voltage regulator *might be* too "slow" to correct the output voltage as needed. But -- this is really just more of a "safety measure", not necessary a design requirement.

Comment: @jeffpkamp Alternatively, you can always just cut the live cable going to the starter (anywhere that's convenient!) and just attach both open ends into a high-current breakaway connector. So, whenever you want to use the capacitor jump starter kit *instead* of the depleted battery, simply just open the connector and stick your jump starter in. Everything *but* the starter is still connected to the battery (so everything's alright), but now you can easily start the car with the jump starter *without any drain* from the jump starter into the depleted battery.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to disconnect car battery.
A relatively dead battery will have s high impedance and when I first apply say 12 to 15V to it the current into the battery will be low compared to the current into the system motor.
While there will be some loss of charge it will be a small portion over the time taken to start the engine.

Answer (score 0):

My [previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/533426/175762) spawned quite a discussion afterwards, so I [decided to add another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125751/when-should-i-add-another-answer/125752) here after a number of clarifications.

If modifications to existing vehicle circuitry are allowed, it seems the goal can be accomplished by putting a high-current SPDT "selector" before the car starter, like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEsggL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where R-(misc) is just the usual load when the car is off, often comprised of things like the clock, or radio, or even the "ECU" in some cars (which also get "reset" when the battery is disconnected). Since R-(misc) is always connected in the above circuit, resetting said components should never be required.

So, in the above circuit, once the capacitor jump-starter is charged, it's connected to the "free" (or unused) throw of the selector and the system ground, and now the vehicle may be started once the ignition is pressed -- *without* having the jump starter discharge anything into the depleted battery.

Comment: It should be rather obvious that such modifications are both not allowed, and also physically impractical.  Do you realize the magnitude of the currents involved, and why are you disregarding the issues previously explained in responses to your existing answer about operating a vehicle without its storage battery connected?  Your proposal amounts to the same as the manual disconnection of the battery, which was well explained to be inadvisable.

Comment: Well, can't you just find a "high current" spdt then? Also, with regards to the [load dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_dump) you're referring to, it seems there are also special protection devices out there (Wikipedia brings up TVS diodes, varistors, etc...) to protect whatever component(s) might be vulnerable. And also in my answer above the battery is never disconnected from anything except the car starter (I think the car starter can withstand a battery disconnect. Otherwise, every car would turn into an expensive 
 brick the second one disconnects the battery!).

Comment: I take it you've never seen the "relay switch" which is used to connect a car starter?  Think the scale of plumbing, not "wiring".  That was a nice greasy-hands afternoon in my apartment building's parking lot.  A little bending got it to work long enough to drive to the auto parts store.

Comment: I've seen them, they're not that large. I haven't had to replace one yet, although you mention that can take a bit of elbow grease to do (as probably some other things involving the starter mechanism too!)

Comment: You have a funny idea of "not that large" !  Anyway, the overall point you're missing is that a practical solution doesn't try to avoid the battery as a load, it just times things so that it's only exposed to the battery during the brief actual attempt at starting.  No modification of the vehicle electrical system needed!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well, I was trying to address the question "as is" : ) Of course, a good general capacitor jump starter should be strong enough to spare *some* amount of discharge into the battery while simultaneously starting the engine too

Comment: @ChrisStratton Besides, the OP can always just simply cut the live cable going to the starter (anywhere that's convenient!) and just attach both open ends into a high-current breakaway connector. So, whenever they want to use the capacitor jump starter kit *instead* of the depleted battery, they can simply open the connector and stick their jump starter in. Everything *but* the starter is still connected to the battery (so everything's alright), but now they can jump start *without any drain* into the depleted battery. Just don't forget to reconnect the battery back to the starter when done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the cap charging circuit (resistor/diode in parallel with a dc boost circuit ( 14.5volt max)) on the cars "run" circuit. Have the cap connected across a separate contactor with the contactor's coil hooked up to "start" . run the cap hot wire straight to the starter. your cap can charge if need be with the ignition in "run" .  with the engine running the cap will recharge at a safe rate if you designed the charge circuit well. with the key "off" cap is isolated. There will be a short period with the cap connected to the battery before the  contact inside the starter motor engages after the starter gear slides into the crankshaft's gear.  The amount of current going into the battery for this short a time will be insignificant. the 14.5 volt spike to the system will not hurt anything either.

Answer (score -3):

It seems problem goes both ways -- preventing either component from discharging into the other due to any difference in potential.

Also, if your "super capacitor jump starter" is dead, then your system should be able to "fallback" to just using the battery instead too.

Here is a simple schematic that might help accomplish this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxTH3c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note -- that "circular voltage element" depicted is just your rectified alternator. In most standard vehicle electrical systems,

1. It's only ever "on" when the engine is *successfully running*, and *always disconnected* otherwise.
2. It has a special *built-in* voltage regulator ensuring a steady 13.5-14.5V no matter how the RPM or your electrical load changes during vehicle operation.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think the battery is *supposed* to charge the jump starter

Comment: Not really -- a standard car battery is used *only* for starting the engine and small-power tasks like keeping the system clock alive. When the car is finally running, however, that's when the engine *alternator* is supposed to charge everything. Having a car battery charge anything while the engine is off is very wasteful, *especially a high-energy supercapacitor* --- since, remember, even in the world of ideal components, you cannot even charge an *ideal* capacitor with an *ideal* voltage source without half of the energy already just going to waste!

Comment: Furthermore, by discharging the battery into a depleted supercapacitor while the car is turned off, you're also reducing the available voltage for the starter for the *next time* you need to start the car. Which could also make the starting even more troublesome!

Comment: how do you think the supercaps get depleted?

Comment: Simple -- let's just start the car several times in a row but not let it run long enough to charge the battery back up between each time. Or let's say the weather is cold and we got unlucky and just had multiple failed starting attempts. Now the super-capacitor is depleted.

Comment: supercapacitor jump starters actually *rely* on charging from the nearly-drained battery. The idea is that you hook it up to your battery, wait a few minutes for the boost converter to do its thing, then use the supercapacitor to provide enough of an impulse of current to start the engine, which then runs the alternator to recharge the battery.

Comment: Also I get the impression that you think this is something that's always connected to the battery; a jump starter is only connected when it's needed, just like jump starting from another car's alternator.

Comment: For convenience, I'd imagine one would just want to install a system that stays always connected and can be just be activated in dire situations automatically with zero user action / involvement or knowledge at all.

Comment: That might be convenient! I'm pretty sure that's not what the question is asking about, and it's not what anything I've seen on the market does.

Comment: Interesting -- my understanding is that the purpose of supercapacitor starting systems is to *relieve* the battery of all starting operations as much as possible, except in worst-case or fallback scenarios. High current draws are not good for batteries, and capacitors are much more capable at that. So, I was intending to replace the battery as a car starter -- except for the "worst-case" or fallback  scenarios -- and use the super capacitors instead for all the high-current demanding applications.

Comment: The worst-case or "fallback" scenarios are also described at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/221531/supercapacitors-as-car-batteries/221538 (although the OP may not have been convinced)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116629/discussion-between-manrow-and-hearth).

Comment: @ManRow The idea is the of the SupCap bank capacity is about 2 orders of magnitude less than the car batter, so that even a depleted battery could charge it multiple times, giving it enough power to start the car.  This question was for a jump starter, not a starter assist (which is another idea).

Comment: Well, if you allow modifying your existing vehicle circuitry, I'd imagine you could just place some voltage-controlled SPDT (with the pole at ground) before the starter and the rest of the car's circuitry. If the car battery drops below some threshold voltage, the switch will "choose" the capacitor jump starter "throw" to run the car starter. And when the car finally turns on (alternator is running), there is now enough voltage to switch back to the battery's "throw" (the usual state).